# Resume previous activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my project. A and B, when user click a button in activity A , i am opening activity B

A --- > B

When user click back button ,application returns the activity A

A

In this activity i have a button named "Resume" , and want to return to activity B without losing anything. is it possible ?

A ----> B (old state)

Thanks.

In activity A

```
 Intent go = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
 go.putExtra("type", 1);
 startActivity(go);
```

Back button click event in Activity B

```
  if(v.getId() == R.id.back)
     super.onBackPressed();
```

Resume Button in Activity A (should resume activity B) , this code is probably wrong

```
 Intent go = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(go);
```

And manifest file,

```
      <activity
        android:name="ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In your manifest,

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ActivityB"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
```

And don't call finish() on activity B while going back. So it should resume the old instance of running activity B.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

So now a new instance of a "singleTop" activity will only be created to handle a new intent if there is no any instance already. However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created.

Edit:

This code works for me:

In `MainActivity`:

```
//Go button's onClick
public void goToSecond(View v) {

    Intent go = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
    startActivity(go);
}

//Resume button's onClick
public void resumeSecond(View v) {

    Intent go = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
    startActivity(go);
}
```

In `ChildActivity`:

```
//Back button's onClick
public void goback(View v) {
    // onBackPressed();
    Intent go = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(go);
}
```

And in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.testingproj.ChildActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
```

At this time, `ChildActivity`'s `onCreate()` is called just when I click on button Go. If I click on Resume button, its not recreated.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. It is re-creating activity B.

Comment: Kept singleTop for it? and didn't finish()? still? @dracula

Comment: Thanks @PurpleDroid. I changed your resumeSecond function to call super.onBackPressed() and now it works :) It doesn't worked with start activity. But i don't know the reason :)

Comment: But now , user can't exit application on back button :(

Comment: User should be able to exit app on Back button on MainActivity (Activity A) @dracula

Comment: It starts ChildActivity (Activity B) again , because it is now at the top of backstack

Comment: Somehow I am not able to update answer: [This](http://pastebin.com/2ER62t9G) works for me. @dracula

Comment: Worked for me , too . But really didn't understand how it works :) Thank you very much.

Comment: The code we just added in `onBackPressed` will exit the application. So the Activity 2 won't be started again :) @dracula