# Android preserve state of activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to pass a custom object from one activity to another. The way this works is I have a `ListView` in my `MainActivity` that is empty when the app first starts. There is a button that leads to my `RecordActivity`. After the user fills out data they press a "done" button that passes the object back to my `MainActivity` and places it in the `List`. This works fine, however when I want to add a second object it just replaces the first instead of just adding it to the list. I'm assuming this is because I'm recreating my `MainActivity` everytime I call  `startActivity(intent)`. I need to save the state of my `MainActivity` and after searching I could not find a thread that solves my problem.

Here is the code in my `RecordActivity` to pass the object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("newRecord", EXTRA_RECORD);
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is my code to retrieve this in my `MainActivity`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    Record addedRecord = extras.getParcelable("newRecord");
    adapter.add(addedRecord);
}
```

with the onNewIntent method:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        Record addedRecord = extras.getParcelable("newRecord");
        recordArrayList.add(addedRecord);
        adapter.add(addedRecord);
    }

}
```

The `adapter` is my `ArrayAdapter` that populates the `ListView`

**Edit:**

I should note that I want this list to be persistent so that every time the app opens the list is already there from the last time. I don't know if this effects my problem since I will need to use a `SharedPreference` to store my list

**Solution**

In the `onNewintent` method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

should be:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Comment: Did you try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in manifest for that activity?

Comment: You can also add these values to an application class that stays alive for the live of the application. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) is the docs.

Comment: @MysticMagic I have not, do I add that to my MainActivity? I have never used the launchMode attribute before

Comment: The activity for which you want to preserve state if its already started. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24508856/1777090) I have explained how that works with a reference. See that

Comment: @MysticMagic I added that and now my object is not being added at all. My RecordActivity is currently a child activity of my MainActivity, do I need to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line while starting your `MainActivity`;

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Also `onCreate` method at `MainActiviy` is not going to be invoked after calling this. You have to handle extras at `onNewIntent` method.

**Edit:**

> every time the app opens the list is already there from the last time

You must store the items of your ListView for this purpose at SharedPrefs or SQLLite DB.

Comment: I made that change and my `ListView` is no longer being populated at all

Comment: As I mentioned above you must handle extras onNewIntent method. Did you?

Comment: I did, there may be a mistake in my code for that method, I made the edit in my original question

Comment: I thought it would be invoked automatically, if that's not the case would I just do that in my onCreate method?

Comment: Right now I have a log message that I'm using to debug in my onNewIntent method to check the size of my list. I excluded that log statement from my edit. That message does get printed

Comment: Ok I found my error, I just changed `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` to `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();`

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the `MainActivity` in your `RecordActivity`, you can call `finish()` to return back to the main activity. 
When starting the `RecordActivity` start it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, EXTRA_RECORD_RESULT);
```

But before calling `finish()` you need to send the data back, you can achieve this by:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

And in your main activity this method gets called:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == EXTRA_RECORD_RESULT)
    {
        value = data.getStringExtra("key");         
    }
}
```